# how to do pattern match in Groovy Script?

Tags: java, regex, groovy

I am trying to do pattern matching in Groovy Script. I knew that it is based on JAVA. So I tried re class in JAVA to do pattern match.

I have two patterns:

1)

```
String a = "$ for partA?"
String b = "what is the $ for partA?"
```

I would like to match b with a since a is a subset of b. I tried to use `find()`, but it return me null... I think it probably because $ is a special character.

2)

```
String c = "the $ for partA is xx"
String d = "I know the $ for partA is $5"
```

I have convert `xx` into some pattern by using `c.replace("xx", "\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?|\\w+|\\W+");`(because xx can be anything). But by using `find()`, it seems not working well with `$` as well..

How can I approach to these two issues?

Comment: Check here for groovy matching - http://mrhaki.blogspot.in/2009/09/groovy-goodness-matchers-for-regular.html and escape for `$`

Answer (score 0):

Based on http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.0/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html , `find()` treating your `a` as regex.

In Java, `String` has an `indexOf()` method which simply find you the first occurrence of a string in another.

For your 2nd problem, it is more complicated.  In your string, you will need to escape all characters with special meaning in regex.  My personal advise is either write `a` as a proper regex, or use `indexOf` to match it as a normal string, and handle the ending part separately.

Comment: for the 2nd problem, I tried to use c.quote() to escape the special character, but it seems escape my substitution of xx as well...

Comment: escape it first, and then do your substitution.  (I still think it is quite fragile though...)

Comment: Give us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . There can be too much thing going wrong (e.g. if you are running it under Groovy, even without regex, you need to escape your `$`.

Comment: an example is `String c = "the $ for partA is xx"
String d = "I know the $ for partA is $5" ` I would like to match d with c

Comment: and, `Pattern.quote()` won't work as it simply quote whole string with `\Q...\E` .  So I would still suggest you to write a proper regex

Comment: A really dirty way is : first do `Pattern.quote()` on whole string, then replace xxx with `\Eyour_pattern\Q`.  Or even simpler: replace your "pattern" string with `c.replace('^(.*)xxx(.*)$', '\\Q\\1\\Eyour_pattern\\Q\\2\\E')`

Answer (score 0):

the `$` in double quoted string have a special meaning, so you have to escape it

but single quoted string is a usual `java` string

The following is true:

```
assert 'the $ in string' == "the \$ in string"
```

case 1/

```
String a = '$ for partA?'
String b = 'what is the $ for partA?'
assert b.endsWith(a)

String pattern = '^(what is the )?(.*) for partA\\?$'
assert a.matches(pattern)
assert b.matches(pattern)

println a.replaceAll(pattern,'$2') // $ 
println b.replaceAll(pattern,'$2') // $

assert a.replaceAll(pattern,'$2') == b.replaceAll(pattern,'$2')
```

case 2/

did not understand what you want, but to extract `xx`:

```
String c = 'the $ for partA is xx'
//$ in pattern means end of line so you need to escape it
String v = c.replaceAll('^the \\$ for partA is (.*)$', '$1' )
```